# forever running with -w on vagrant not seeing file changes made in host OS

Tags: node.js, vagrant, forever

I'm running Vagrant for developing my webapp. Inside Vagrant, I'm running Node.js through forever.js, and I launch forever with the `-w` flag (watch files for change, if change is detected, restart server). The change is detected and the server is restarted only if the change was made from within Vagrant.

How can I make forever restart even if the files are modified in the host system?

Comment: The files you modify on the host are part of synchronized folder with the vm ?

Comment: Yes. Vagrant allows me to have a shared folder between the VM and the host, which are `ln`'d together.

Comment: I am not sure the changes are detected on file from symlink, you should configure a sync folder

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: It was a while ago. I don't remember how we fixed it, but I think a clean re-deployment of the VM did the trick.